# What is the difference between an "Element" and a "Cell"?

Tags: jointjs

When I read the documentation on JointJS, I find that there are discussions on "Elements" and "Cells".  What are the differences between them?

Answer (score 1):

In JointJS, the core items on the graph (diagram) are "Elements" and "Links".  Think of an element as the visualization of a node such as a rectangle or circle and a link being a "wire" connecting the two.  The elements and links are the fundamental building blocks in a JointJS model.  Together, these are termed "cells".  So an element is an example of a cell and a link is also an example of a cell.

For example, if we ask the diagram to find me all the cells, it will return a set of all elements *and* links.